# TSQL trigger instead of insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert

I need to replace, after an insert in a certain table, one of the column value if it match with a banned value.

example:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_A]
           ([COL_A]
           ,[COL_B])
     VALUES
           ('TEST'
           ,'TEST1')
```

TEST1 is a banned value and I want to replace it in 'BANNED'.

This is the trigger I wrote but it seems to working properly well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TEST_NAME_INS] ON [dbo].[TEST_A]
 INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_A
    (COL_A
    ,COL_B)
    SELECT 
    COL_A
   ,REPLACE(COL_B, 'TEST1', 'BANNED')
   FROM inserted
   WHERE INSERTED.COL_B IN ('TEST1')
```

The error is that if I insert a different value in COL_B no rows are inserted.

Can you give me a solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the where clause. It will prevent any insert from happening unless the row being inserted has the value 'TEST1'.

Comment: Ok. it works. and if I have a list of banned values that I need to replace?

Comment: I would put that list in a table and use a join to get the value in your replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more values than you want to put in a case statement, you can try using a table to store the banned words and the replacement for them. Then join to that in the insert, something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TEST_NAME_INS] ON [dbo].[TEST_A]
 INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_A
    (COL_A
    ,COL_B)
    SELECT 
    COL_A
   ,CASE WHEN b.banned is null then i.col_b
         ELSE b.replacement
    END
   FROM inserted i
   LEFT JOIN Banned b on i.col_B = b.banned
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TEST_NAME_INS] ON [dbo].[TEST_A]
 INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_A
    (COL_A
    ,COL_B)
    SELECT 
    COL_A
   ,CASE WHEN COL_B ='TEST1' THEN 'BANNED'
         WHEN COL_B ='TEST12' THEN 'BANNED34'
         ELSE COL_B END

   FROM inserted
```

Comment: Ok it works. What if I need a list of banned values? 
ex. TEST1 replace to BANNED
      TEST2 replace to NOTOK

Comment: if I have a big amount of data in my table it could be an issue with the performance?

Comment: The best practice says you should always avoid trigger. For your case  specifically, there are multiple way to achieve except trigger. IMHO, you should handle it in your application code not in database level. Everything depends on your application architecture.